# Faker gem: How to set max. length / range for resp. Company.name / Number.number?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, faker

I use the Faker gem for seeding certain data. How can I set the max. length for a fake Company.name, and how can I set the range for a fake number?

```
name  = Faker::Company.name
```

Here I would like to include the maximum length, since name has a model restriction for max. 40 characters.

```
code_id = Faker::Number.number
```

For code_id I would like a range from 1 to 50. I tried `code_id = Faker::Number.number(from=1, to=50)` but that seems incorrect as on seeding it produced the following error:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/faker-1.4.3/lib/faker/number.rb:4:in 'number'
```

How should I adjust Faker to my needs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the name you can just cut off the extra parts of the generated one (you don't care about half-finished words there, do you?)

```
name = Faker::Company.name[0..40]
```

And for the number you can use `Faker::Number.between` or use core ruby `rand` directly.

```
rand(1..50)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you can override the data with I18n and add your own names with short length:

   ```
   faker:
      name:
       short_names: [Ben, Ava...]
   ```
2. `Faker::Number.between`

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
Faker::Lorem.words(50);
```

It will return 50 words 
https://github.com/Marak/faker.js/wiki/Basic-Random-Data